# Masquerade with nftables

Tags: linux, networking, nat, nftables

I have PC-1 with 2 uplinks (modem1 and modem2) and LAN on eth0 interface:

```
# ip -c -brief addr
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8
eth0             UP             192.168.0.7/24
modem2           UNKNOWN        10.73.15.79/27
modem1           UNKNOWN        10.176.229.31/26
```

('unknown' state for modem1 and modem2 is seemed ok).

I've setup routing as follows:

```
# ip -c rule
0:      from all lookup local
32764:  from 10.73.15.79 lookup 2
32765:  from 10.176.229.31 lookup 1
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

# ip -c route ls table main
default
        nexthop via 10.176.229.32 dev modem1 weight 1
        nexthop via 10.73.15.80 dev modem2 weight 1
10.73.15.64/27 dev modem2 proto kernel scope link src 10.73.15.79
10.176.229.0/26 dev modem1 proto kernel scope link src 10.176.229.31
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.7

# ip -c route ls table 1
default via 10.176.229.32 dev modem1
10.73.15.64/27 dev modem2 scope link
10.176.229.0/26 dev modem1 scope link src 10.176.229.31
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo scope link
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 scope link

# ip -c route ls table 2
default via 10.73.15.80 dev modem2
10.73.15.64/27 dev modem2 scope link src 10.73.15.79
10.176.229.0/26 dev modem1 scope link
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo scope link
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 scope link
```

So, locally on PC-1, I have internet access.

I have also PC-2 within the LAN, and would like to setup masquerade on PC-1 to provide internet for PC-2.

I'm trying the following nftables config:

```
# nft list ruleset
table ip filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        }

        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept;
        }

        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        }
}
table ip nat {
        chain input {
                type nat hook input priority 0; policy accept;
                ip protocol icmp accept
        }

        chain prerouting {
                type nat hook prerouting priority 0; policy accept;
        }

        chain postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
                ip saddr 192.168.0.0/24 oifname "modem*" masquerade
        }

        chain output {
                type nat hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        }
}
```

But it does not work. I have tried several different versions of the config, but unsuccessfully. How can I setup nftables for masquerade?

I also setup:

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward="1"
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Linux kernel 4.19.0

**Edit:**

I have configured masquerade with nftables on another PC successfully. 
The difference noticed by me (I do not know whether it has sense):

On PC-1:

```
# sudo iptables -S
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

On another PC:

```
# sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Comment: What does not work? The masquerading rules are fine, I'd replace `"modem*"` with two lines, one each for `modem1` and `modem2`, though (personal preference). Also +1 for nftables. This is for initial setup, for production use I'd change the default policies, of course.

Comment: @Lenniey ping from PC-2 does not pass. With iftop I see requests from PC-2 on eth0, but uplinks are empty.

Comment: Ah, you are missing your forward entries. Try something like `iifname "eth0" oifname "modem*" accept`, `iifname "modem*" oifname "eth0" ct state established accept` and `iifname "modem*" oifname "eth0" ct state related accept`

Comment: @Lenniey I've added the rules to chain forward of ip filter table. But the result is the same.

Comment: I have configured masquerade with nftables on another PC successfully. Seems the problem is not in nftables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem - `IPV4_DEVCONF_FORWARDING` was unset on `eth0` interface. 
I have set it with help of `libnl` - method `rtnl_link_inet_set_conf`.

**Edit:**

This is the same option `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding`.
Thanks for @A.B.

Comment: afaik IPV4_DEVCONF_FORWARDING for eth0 means sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding. Considering you wrote you enabled the global toggle, this should have been set also for eth0. It would thus have been hard to guess from the question that it wasn't there.

Comment: @A.B. I enabled the global toggle manually but did not realize - I have soft, which can change "forwarding" on an interface.